# "python setup.py egg_info" when installing a module

Tags: python, module, ffmpeg

```
PS C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts> pip install --upgrade setuptools
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-36.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (481kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 481kB 435kB/s
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 28.8.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-28.8.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-28.8.0
Successfully installed setuptools-36.6.0
PS C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts> pip install .\ffmpeg-3.4.tar.bz2
Processing c:\users\adamk\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\scripts\ffmpeg-3.4.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\adamk\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\adamk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-rlpa5bd4-build\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rlpa5bd4-build\
```

I tried many things like updating my `setuptools`. Stil didint work. If someone could help, it would really help! -Adam

Comment: Who told you to install `ffmpeg-3.4.tar.bz2` with `pip` in Python 3.6?

Comment: A friend. Wait so it's not supposed too be installed with pip?

Comment: While you are using windows you will need installation file for windows. Go get it here and install it as a normal software. http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: Alright, going to do as you said.